# Safari Web Inspector-esque functionality in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, jquery-ui, interface, safari

Just starting out in Objective-C, so I'm curious as to how some apps that I enjoy function interface-wise. I've cloned a few apps from Github into Xcode, and I'm looking for something similar to Safari's [Web Inspector](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html) where I can highlight portions of the application and see what piece of code they refer to?

I think it may have something to do with Interface Builder, but I'm not sure where to begin... help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't exist AFAIK. Interface Builder doesn't show a representation of your code, it allows to you to lay out (serialized) interface elements to your app graphically.

Comment: Heh, I forgot I wrote this ages ago. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Haha you're welcome. Stack is a wiki as much as it is a community, so it's never good to leave questions unanswered, no matter how simple/foolish they might seem in retrospect :) ...Plus we both get points :D